# Firefox: WebRequest API vs Deceptive Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, webrequest, safe-browsing-api

I'm developing a Firefox add-on which does block the malicious URLs. The problem is that sometimes `Firefox` render its own deceptive warning page and sometime it allows the extension to render its own warning page.

How can I bypass the deceptive page warning programmatically?

The above behaviour is working fine on Chrome.

Comment: Some could would help. Like what you tried and where exactly are you facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Abdul Basit.

The easy way is with the privacy WebExtension API, here the documentation on the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/privacy

> Access and modify various privacy-related browser settings. To use the
> privacy API, you must have the "privacy" API permission.

You can already use `services.safeBrowsingEnabled` for Chrome, Opera, Edge, but Firefox not yet.

You can play around with the request status code 400, because it is related to the deceptive request routing.

Good luck.